# What causes gnutls "One of the involved algorithms has insufficient security level." error?

Tags: opensuse, gnutls

My evoluion mail (opensuse tumbleweed) complain about the mail server's certificate. It looks like gnutls reject the certificate. Can anyone give me some pointers to the problem? Thanks

> ### Information for package gnutls:
>
> Repository     : openSUSE-20181224-0
> Name           : gnutls
> Version        : 3.7.1-1.1 Arch           :
> x86_64 Vendor         : openSUSE

Answer (score 3):

While trying to setup the exchange email from scratch with gnome-shell online-account, the server could not be contacted with Error Connecting to Microsoft Exchange server:

`Code:6 -- Unexpected response from server`

Searching for the cause, I found this solution [1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/1866974/comments/3), basically lower the
system-wide security level or accepting shorter key or old algorithm:

`update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY`

[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/1866974/comments/3) [The Diffie-Hellman prime sent by the server is not acceptable]

Conclusion from my observation, the certificate may contain legacy encription algorithms or short keys that are no longer secure for newer TLS version.